# Tensorflow: how to install roi_pooling user_op

Tags: python, tensorflow, detection, roi

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618960/tensorflow-how-to-insert-custom-input-to-existing-graph) post by HediBy that this ROI_POOLING user_op implementation works: [LINK](https://github.com/yuxng/tensorflow/)

I used bazel build

```
-c opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:roi_pooling.so to generate the so file (after installing tensorflow)
```

But when I use `tf.load_op_library to load roi_pooling.so`, I get this weird error:

```
 tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: /home/fishdrop/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/roi_pooling.so: undefined symbol: _Z21ROIPoolForwardLaucherPKffiiiiiiS0_PfPiRKN5Eigen9GpuDeviceE
```

Any ideas? has anyone else been successful with this user_op?

Comment: Are you trying to run on a GPU? Your bazel build command line is incomplete, but if you are trying to run on a GPU, I would try compiling with the following command line : `bazel build --config=cuda -c opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:roi_pooling.so`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the tip i just found out that the error occured when I built the user_op without GPU support. I reinstalled tensorflow v 0.10, with GPU support, and placed all user_op files inside //tensorflow/core/us‌​er_ops.

If I compile the user_op using bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/core/us‌​er_ops:roi_pooling.so (the addition of --config=cuda isn't in the tensorflow user_op documentation), the user_op now works.. I guess this issue could now be closed